# How to get parameters using express in node

Tags: node.js, express

I am certain that this is super easy, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this does not work.

So trying to write an application where a user can search, gets a link, and if clocked it calls a second route, passing a variable while it is at it. Sounds simple, so thought I.

The idea is that each link generated gets a link like "localhost:3000/getcan/:[id]"
So for our example, I am trying to get 22 into a variable if I try to go to webpage

```
"localhost:3000/getcan/:22"
```

To set up the route, I set the following in app.js

```
app.use('/getcan/:*', getcan);
```

This seems to work, and if I put anything that calls /getcan/: I go to the right route.

The route it self looks as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET getcan page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var canid = req.params.canid;
    console.log("Got the following id " + canid)
    res.render('getcan', { title: 'ResourceEdge', reqcan: canid });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I think the problem is with `router.get('/'` but if I make any changes (tried get('/getcan/:canid) it all blows up with a 404.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change app.use to:

```
app.use('/getcan', getcan);
```

And your router to:

```
/* GET getcan page. */
router.get('/:canid', function(req, res, next) {
    var canid = req.params.canid;
    console.log("Got the following id " + canid)
    res.render('getcan', { title: 'ResourceEdge', reqcan: canid });
});
```

Then call your route using: http://localhost:3000/getcan/22

Comment: That worked perfect. Can I ask a followup question, now that I have it in canid, how do I get access to it in the webpage (i.e it will render getcan, but I need a way to get the variable over to angular or javascript to get the data requested)

Comment: Well, if you're using something like angular, then you shouldn't be using render(). You should be serving static HTML and then using $http to call your Node routes, which would respond with some sort of data using res.json(). Using res.render() all you can really do is stick the variable into a script tag using a codeblock in whatever templating engine you're using

Comment: Ignoring what I should do at the moment, how would I do it if I wanted to? The content would not really be that good for single page app so really want to just load another page based on it:)

Comment: This could potentially be a difficult answer. I'd make a new question, indicating exactly what you want to do, including the code for the page you're rendering.